# MiniCssExtractPlugin extract css file from application global styles webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using Angular 6 framework along with webpack 4 module bundler. I have 2 webpack configuration files.

Global application styles are placed inside 'Content/Styles' path. Each angular component style is placed in the corresponding component folder inside 'scripts/app' path. e.g 'scripts/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.scss'

Webpack common configuration contains the following rule for 'scss' files.

webpack.common.js:

```
module: {
   rules: [
      ...
      {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ["to-string-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
                exclude: [helpers.root("Content", "Styles")]
      },
      ....
   ]
}
```

Webpack dev configuation contains the following rule for global 'scss' files.

webpack.dev.js:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    ...
    {
                test: /\.scss$/,                    
                include: [helpers.root("Content", "Styles")],
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: {
                                safe: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            plugins: function () { // post css plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                                return [
                                    require("precss"),
                                    require("autoprefixer")
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            },
         ....
  ]
}
```

I would like to inject extracted global css file to index.html. The problem is that the dev rule is not applied when i have the 'include' option. When this option is missing, the rule is applied for all scss files of my application creating a 'css' file containing all component styles also. Can someone tell me what am i am doing wrong?